# Generate String array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have a string like follows

```
String items = "["car","van","jeep"......]";
```

I used following code to convert that string to get string array like follows

```
String[] vehicles = {"car","van","jeep"....};
```

code is

```
items = items.substring(1,items.length()-1); //this is to drop "[","]" brackets
String[] ret = items.split(",");
for (String arr : ret){
    returner.add(arr.substring(1,arr.length()-1)); // this is for drop "\"" 's
}
ret = new String[returner.size()];
ret = returner.toArray(ret);
return ret;
```

this string array is use for spinner in android.

then i want to know is there any mechanism efficient than this?

thank u

Comment: You could treat [...] block as a json array of strings. I would recommend you to take a look f.e. at gson library (not saying that this is more efficient - but it would definitely look much cleaner). Why do you need more efficient solution, anyway? Is the array that big?

Comment: @scana array contains about 70 elements

Answer (score 0):

If `"` is only used to delimit the strings, then you could do this:

```
items = items.substring(1,items.length()-1); //this is to drop "[","]" brackets
items=items.replace("\"","");
String[] ret = items.split(",");
return ret;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably make it a tiny bit faster by doing:

```
items = items.substring(2,items.length()-2); //drops first+last bracket and quote
String[] ret = items.split("\",\"");//drops all quotes and commas
return ret;
```

Otherwise, is it really causing any performance issues or are you falling into the trap of early optimization?

Comment: Just edited my post, forgot you needed to change the first substring.

Comment: this gives output like this
"car
van
jeep"

Comment: Are you sure? Java documents states that split will return an array of strings. But you are saying it is returning a modified string. This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: that means first element in array starts with " \" ", as well as last element of the array ends with " \" " 

like "cars and jeep"

other elements are fine

Comment: Did you see my edit? Your first line needs to be items = items.substring(2,items.length()-2);

Comment: Oh and what is "returner"? Why are you copying an array instead of just returning it?

Comment: I didn't see it, then i got it thank u for explanation @rhett

Comment: Sorry, I should have just put it all in the code block. Just edited it again to make it simpler.